# GNU debugger __text_start () at wrong filepath

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sparc

First a little preface: I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux and the Gaisler BCC version of GCC for cross-compiling (aka "`machine-gcc`" where the `machine` is `sparc-gaisler-elf` in this case).

I compile a simple hello world program for debugging like this

```
$ sparc-gaisler-elf-gcc -g hello.c -o hello
```

Then I open the simulator for the particular processor with the GNU debugger (GDB) as a server

```
$ tsim-leon3 -gdb
...
gdb interface: using port 1234
Starting GDB server. Use Ctrl-C to stop waiting for connection.
```

In another bash session I start a remote GDB and connect to the server

```
$ sparc-gaisler-elf-gdb -ex "target extended-remote localhost:1234"
...
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
```

This works fine. But if I try to load the `hello` executable I get a problem

```
$ sparc-gaisler-elf-gdb -ex "target extended-remote localhost:1234" hello
...
Remote debugging using localhost:1234

__text_start () at /opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S:167
167  /opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S: No such file or directory.
     in /opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S
Current language:  auto; currently asm

(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/<username>/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/examples/hello/hello

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__text_start () at /opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S:167
167     in /opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S
```

Now, with my Windows Subsystem for Linux setup I have the particular file it's looking for at

```
/mnt/c/Users/<username>/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S
```

instead of in `/opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/...`

How can I tell it where to find this file?

---

#### Update

I tried setting `dir` as per Employed Russian's answer

```
(gdb) dir /mnt/c/Users/<user>/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap
Source directories searched: /mnt/c/Users/<user>/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap:$cdir:$cwd

(gdb) list
162             BAD_TRAP; BAD_TRAP; BAD_TRAP; BAD_TRAP; ! 78 - 7B undefined
163             BAD_TRAP; BAD_TRAP; BAD_TRAP; BAD_TRAP; ! 7C - 7F undefined
164
165             /* trap_instruction 0x80 - 0xFF */
166             /* NOTE: "ta 5" can be generated by compiler. */
167             SOFT_TRAP;                                    !  0 System calls
168             SOFT_TRAP;                                    !  1 Breakpoints
169             SOFT_TRAP;                                    !  2 Division by zero
170             FLW_TRAP;                                     !  3 Flush windows
171             SOFT_TRAP;                                    !  4 Clean windows

(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/<user>/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/examples/hello/hello

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__text_start () at /opt/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap/trap_table_mvt.S:167
167             SOFT_TRAP;                                    !  0 System calls
```

Even though it's still saying `/opt/...` it seems to have found the right file now. However, I don't know why it's giving a segmentation fault.

Comment: Why not try to move that file to `/opt` path?

Comment: @Biswapriyo With WSL, `/opt/` is located in a Windows system hidden folder in `%localappdata%`. It's not really practical. Having said that, I perhaps could create a copy of the relevant files in there?

Comment: Linux Command: `sudo cp /mnt/c/xyz /opt/xyz`.

Comment: Are you looking to change the source search path for GDB? You might want to try using the `set substitute-path from to` command

Comment: @Hasturkun I wouldn't know. I tried it and I don't think it solved the problem. Will update the question soon

Comment: After some investigation I've realised that this version of GDB does not work like normal GDB. The `__text_start ()` thing is a bit of a red herring, though it occurs because you can't seem to load a file properly into `sparc-gaisler-elf-gdb` if you pass it in the command line. Going to reword the question and post my own answer later

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell it where to find this file?

With the `directory` command.

```
(gdb) dir /mnt/c/Users/<username>/bcc-2.0.4-gcc/src/libbcc/shared/trap
(gdb) list  # should find the file in the new location
```

See also [source path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) and [set substitite-path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#set-substitute_002dpath).

Comment: I'm still getting a segmentation fault. I've updated my question

Comment: @binaryfunt Your question was about "wrong path". Your new question is about something else entirely. You should accept this answer, and ask a new question.

Comment: Actually it seems like I asked the wrong question. What I thought was GDB getting the wrong filepath doesn't seem to have been the problem at all, and actually I need to find out why it's printing out the `__text_start ()` thing and why the segmentation fault is happening. I'm going to take a break from this until tomorrow